# Populating and Accessing ClaimsIdentity in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a .NET Core 2.1 application where I have an authentication handler which I use to extract the value of a header.

How do I add this value to my ClaimsIdentity, and how can I then access it from my controller?

I have the following code which works on all my controller actions:

```
public class CustomAuthHandler : AuthenticationHandler<CustomAuthOptions>
{
    public CustomAuthHandler(IOptionsMonitor<CustomAuthOptions> options, ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock)
        : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
    }

    protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        // Get Authorization header value
        if (!Request.Headers.TryGetValue(HeaderNames.Authorization, out var authorization))
        {
            return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail("Cannot read authorization header."));
        }

        var key = authorization.FirstOrDefault() ?? "";

        var token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(authorization);

        var identities = new List<ClaimsIdentity> { new ClaimsIdentity("custom auth type") };
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(new ClaimsPrincipal(identities), Options.Scheme);

        return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket));
    }
}
```

I think what I need to do is pass my token variable into my ClaimsIdentity?  If so, how do I do that, and then how do I access my Claims from my API controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't adding any claims to your identity, and you're returning multiple identities as a bonus.

Authentication handlers are responsible for creating a full identity, rather than appending a single claim and its unclear which you want here. If your token is the sole source of truth about an identity then you'd create an identity like so

```
var claims = new[]
{
    new Claim("myClaimName","valueExtractedFromToken")
};

var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, context.Scheme.Name));
var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(validateCertificateContext.Principal, Scheme.Name);
return AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);
```

There's a couple of examples at https://github.com/blowdart/idunno.Authentication, where I illustrate basic auth and certificate auth.

If authentication is handled by something else, and you just want to add a claim (for example you have cookie auth then there are events in the options class for each handler where you can add your own code after authentication runs where you can add a claim to the existing identity.